# Sql count : taking count of rows joining 2 tables

Tags: sql

Lets say i have 2 tables Master and slave .
Master table contains master_name and master_id , Slave table has Slave_id, slave_name and master_id.

sample data.

```
master_id Master_name  Master_status      slave_id  slave_name  master_id status
1         x               online              1          a          1       online
2         y               online              2          b          1       online
3         z               offline             3          c          2       offline
                                              4          d          3       offline
                                              5          e          3       online
```

the expected result i m trying to obtain is,

```
master_id  no_of_slave
   1             2
   2             0
```

i want to get the no: of online slaves each online masters have.

sorry for the late edit.

Comment: Which RDBMS? What are your thoughts on the problem at hand?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `LEFT JOIN` like this one:

```
SELECT m.master_id
     , count(s.slave_id) AS no_of_slave
FROM master m 
LEFT JOIN slave s 
     ON m.master_id = s.master_id
GROUP BY m.master_id;
```

Result:

```
╔═══════════╦═════════════╗
║ MASTER_ID ║ NO_OF_SLAVE ║
╠═══════════╬═════════════╣
║         1 ║           2 ║
║         2 ║           1 ║
║         3 ║           2 ║
╚═══════════╩═════════════╝
```

#### [See this SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/1e136/7)

Comment: I might suggest a LEFT JOIN to return masters without slaves.

Comment: @bluefeet - Yeah better. Updated.

Answer (score 1):

Use the below query:

```
Select m.master_id, count(s.master_id) as no_of_slave 
       FROM master m 
            JOIN slave s 
            ON m.master_id = s.master_id
            GROUP By m.master_id;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select 
    a.master_id,
    count(b.slave_id) 
from 
    master a,
    slave b 
where 
     a.master_id=b.master_id 
group by 
     a.master_id
```

Comment: Why are you using commas to join the tables?  Why not ANSI standard syntax with a JOIN?

Comment: imo the commas are easier to read for small joins and they work pretty much everywhere as a synonym to joins.

Comment: Please read [bad habits to kick using old style join syntax](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins).

Comment: yes, but _for_small_joins_ , for multiple joins or complex joins I always use the proper join syntax.

Comment: If you always use proper joins on multiple joins, why not use it all the time?

Comment: as i said, for small joins (as in simple, not "few rows") they are more readable.

Comment: That reasoning IMO makes no sense. Also, if the OP wants to return all masters even those without slaves, i.e. a LEFT JOIN would you switch to proper ANSI syntax?

Answer (score 0):

```
select    master_id, count(1)
from      Slave
group by  master_id
order by  master_id
```

will just give you masters that have slaves, and you don't even need to join with master if tables are big

Answer (score 0):

You can use this. This will work.

```
select m.master_id,(select count(*) from slave s where s.master_id = m.master_id) as no_of_slave from master m
```

Answer (score 0):

```
  SELECT master_id, count(*) AS no_of_slave
    FROM slave
GROUP BY master_id
ORDER BY master_id;
```

Answer (score 0):

You're not interested in master names so a join is not required, you have all necessary info in the Slave table:

```
select master_id, count(slave_id) as no_of_slave
from Slave
group by master_id
order by master_id --remove this line, if ordering of master ids is not important
;
```

If a given master id is not in this result, this means it has no slaves.